# Why is my page showing a white part at the bottom of the screen in portrait view

Tags: html, css, landscape-portrait

I'm having a problem with my webpage.

I'm converting a template for a friend into a new webpage.

The original template shapes pretty good for phones in both portrait and landscape, but after the edits i made it only works in landscape and on pc.

On portrait view it gives me a big white part underneath the webpage. Which is pretty strange because on pc and in landscape view it stops at the bottom of the page where it should with the footer.

I made only a few adjustments on the css and only adjustment i made which could have anything to do with it is html height which i set from 100% to 1500px but that was also done because of this issue, so i doubt this will have anything to do with this.

I just can't seem to figure out why it doesn't shape to the screen anymore.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;}

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

body
{ font: normal 85% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #FFF url(../images/background.jpg) repeat;
  color: #000;
}

p
{ padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 100% }

img
{ border: 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{ font: normal 175% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #1D1D1D;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;}

h2
{ font: normal 165% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

h3
{ font: normal 130% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h4, h5, h6
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0px 0;
  font: normal 150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;}

h5, h6
{ font: normal 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  padding-bottom: 15px;}

a
{ color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;}

a:hover
{ text-decoration: none;}

ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 30px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 100%;}

ol
{ margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;}

ol li
{ margin: 0 0 11px 0;}

#main, #header, #banner, #menubar, #site_content, #footer, #content_bottom, #footercopyright
{ margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;}
  
#footercopyright{
 height: 20px;
 width: 960px;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align:center;
 top:auto;
 padding-top: 20px;
   text-align: center; 
   background: transparent;
   color: #1D1D1D;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF;} 

#footercopyright a, #footercopyright a:hover
{ color: #1D1D1D;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;}

#footercopyright a:hover
{ text-decoration: underline;}

#main
{ background: transparent;}
  
#header
{ width: 960px;
  height: 120px;
  background: transparent;}

#banner
{ width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  background: transparent;}

#menubar
{ width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}
  
#welcome
{ width: 960px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;} 
  
#welcome_slogan
{ width: 960px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;}   
   
#welcome H1
{ font: normal 300% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #1D1D1D;}

#welcome_slogan H1
{ font: normal 200% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #1D1D1D;}  
  
ul#menu
{ margin:0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;}

ul#menu li
{ padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  display: inline;
  background: transparent;}

ul#menu li a
{ float: left;
  font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 24px;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
  padding: 16px 20px 10px 20px;
  background: transparent; } 
  
ul#menu li.current a
{ color: #FFF;
  background: #323232;
  text-shadow: none;}
  
ul#menu li:hover a
{ color: #FFF;
  background: #323232;
  text-shadow: none;}

#site_content
{ width: 940px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #323232;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 0px 0px 15px 15px;} 

.sidebar_container
{ float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
  width: 215px;
  padding: 0;}

.sidebar
{ float: left;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;}

.sidebar_item
{ font: normal 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 215px;}

.sidebar h2
{ padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
  font: normal 140% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}  

#content
{ width: 680px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;}

.content_item
{ width: 680px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;}
  
.content_image
{ float: left; 
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;}
  
.content_container
{ width: 320px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;}
  
#content_bottom
 { width: 960px;
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;} 
  
#content_bottom p
 { color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF; }  

#content_bottom h4
{ color: #000;
  text-shadow: none;}
  
.content_bottom_container_box
{ width: 295px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;}

.content_bottom_container_boxl
{ width: 295px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;}
  
#footer
{ width: 960px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center; 
  background: transparent;
  color: #1D1D1D;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF;}

#footer a, #footer a:hover
{ color: #1D1D1D;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;}

#footer a:hover
{ text-decoration: underline;}
  
 .readmore
{ font: bold 110% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 95px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 7px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}
  
 .readmore a
{ color: #1D1D1D;}
 
 .button_small
{ font: normal 110% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 15px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 7px;
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}
  
.button_small a
{ color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 5px;}

.form_settings
{ margin: 15px 0 0 0;}

.form_settings p
{ padding: 0 0 4px 0;}

.form_settings span
{ float: left; 
  width: 280px; 
  text-align: left;}
  
.form_settings input, .form_settings textarea
{ padding: 2px; 
  width: 299px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid #E5E5DB; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;}
  
.form_settings input[type="checkbox"]
{ padding: 2px 0; 
  width: 15px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 0; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;
  margin: 28px 0;}

.form_settings .submit
{ font: 100% arial; 
  width: 99px; 
  margin: 0 0 0 206px; 
  height: 26px;
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer; 
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  color: #FFF;}

.slideshow {
  width: 680px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;}
  
/* styling for the slideshow on the homepage */
ul.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  width: 680px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;}
  
ul.slideshow li {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;}
 
ul.slideshow li.show {
  z-index: 500;}
 
ul img {
  border: none;}
  
ul.white{
  color:#FFF;
}
 
#slideshow-caption {
  width: 680px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 500;}
 
#slideshow-caption .slideshow-caption-container {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; 
  background: transparent url(../images/transparent.png) repeat;  
  z-index: 1000;}
 
#slideshow-caption p {
  padding: 0;
  font: normal 130% arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;}

.linkwithoutline A:link {text-decoration: none}
.linkwithoutline A:visited {text-decoration: none}
.linkwithoutline A:active {text-decoration: none}
.linkwithoutline A:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

.linkwithoutline-black A:link {text-decoration: none}
.linkwithoutline-black A:visited {text-decoration: none}
.linkwithoutline-black A:active {text-decoration: none}
.linkwithoutline-black A:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
.linkwithoutline-black {color:#FFF; left:50%;}

#news{width:208px; margin:23px 0 22px 19px}
#news h2{ height:23px; background:url(../images/h_news.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; position:relative; border-bottom: #545400 3px dotted;  margin-bottom:5px}
.newsstory{width:201px; margin-left:7px; border-bottom: #545400 3px dotted; margin-bottom:5px}
.newsstory p span.date{display:block; width:74px; height:16px; padding:2px 0 0 11px; font:12px/14px Trebuchet MS, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; background:#d3d7db; color:#22454d; margin-bottom:7px;}
.newsstory p {margin-bottom:5px;}
.newsstory p a{color:#22454d; font:10px/14px Tahoma, sans-serif; text-decoration:none}
.newsstory p a:hover{color:#a65b99; }
#news ul.bullet{margin:0 0 0 108px}
```

```html
<?php
// Get our database connector
require("includes/(connection-file)");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Massagetherapeut Henk Dias</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Massagetherapeut Henk Dias" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Massage Therapeut Henk Dias Massagetherapeut" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_slide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- facebook likes en shares script -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
   <div id="banner">
     <div id="welcome">
       <h1>Massagetherapeut Henk Dias</h1>
     </div><!--close welcome-->
     <div id="welcome_slogan">
       <h1>Your Company Slogan Here</h1>
     </div><!--close welcome_slogan-->
   </div><!--close banner-->
    </div><!--close header-->

 <div id="menubar">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about/" title="Over Mij">Over Mij</a></li>
        <li><a href="intake/" title="Intake">Intake</a></li>
        <li><a href="massage/" title="Massages">Massages</a></li>
        <li><a href="tarieven/" title="Tarieven">Tarieven</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--close menubar--> 
    
 <div id="site_content">  

   <div class="sidebar_container">       
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>Nieuws</h2>
           <?php   


                $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<div class=\"newsstory\" style=\"border-bottom: #1867c7 3px dotted;\">";
    echo "<p>";
    echo !empty($row['date']) ? ("<h3> <u>". $row['date'] . "</u></h3>") : '';
 echo "<p>";
    echo $row['news'];
 echo "</p>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}

?>
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar--> 
 <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="sidebar_item">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/massagetherapeutHenkDias/" data-width="232" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
<br /> <br />
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.massagepraktijkanne.nl/" data-width="232" data-type="button_count"></div>
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->       
       </div><!--close sidebar_container--> 
 
   <div class="slideshow">
     <ul class="slideshow">
          <li class="show"><img width="680" height="250" src="images/home_1.jpg" alt="&quot;Time to relax&quot;" /></li>
          <li><img width="680" height="250" src="images/home_2.jpg" alt="&quot;Give yourself a moment&quot;" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>     
  
   <div id="content">
        <div class="content_item">
     <p>bla</p>  
  </div><!--close content_item-->
      </div><!--close content-->   
 </div><!--close site_content--> 
    
 </br>
    </br> 
 
  </div><!--close main-->
  
  <div id="footer">
  <a href="/" title="Home">HOME</a> | <a href="about/" title="Over Mij">OVER MIJ</a> | <a href="intake/" title="Intake">INTAKE</a> | <a href="massage/" title="Massages">MASSAGES</a> | <a href="tarieven/" title="Tarieven">TARIEVEN</a> | <a href="contact/" title="Contact">CONTACT</a>

 </div>   <!--close footer--> 

 <div id="footercopyright">
     <strong>Copyright &copy; Massagetherapeut Henk Dias | Designed by <span class="linkwithoutline-black"><a class="linkwithoutline-black" href="mailto:webmaster@massagetherapeuthenkdias.be">W. Vermeylen</a></span></strong>  </div> <!--close footercopyright--> 
   
   </br>
   </br>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of portrait view]

Edit: just noticed my copyright footer is screwing with it, but no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Your body isn't set to 100%

```
body {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: like i said, it was set to 100% but that wasn't helping so i set it to max height of the background image which didn't change a thing...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the issue myself :) I set a padding-bottom for the footer that was doing this. Without this i works like a charm :)